# Angularjs Controller calling Service - .success if not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a controller to call a service that will make an `$http` request, but right now I've only set my service to return a string because I want to make sure it works and is calling properly.

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: monitorData.requestEvent(...).success is not a function
```

My code below:

**Controller**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('monitorApp')
        .controller('eventCtrl', eventCtrl);

    eventCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'monitorData'];
    function eventCtrl($scope, $routeParams, monitorData) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.eventid = $routeParams.eventid;
        vm.event = {};

        vm.getData = function(eventid) {
            console.log("getData variable accessed");
            monitorData.requestEvent(eventid)
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(e) {
                    console.log("Error");
                });
            return false;
        };

        vm.getData(vm.eventid);

    }

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('monitorApp')
        .service('monitorData', monitorData);

    monitorData.$inject = ['$http'];
    function monitorData($http) {
        var requestEvent = function(eventid) {
            var gas = "Event " + eventid + " requested.."
            console.log(gas);
            return gas;
        };

        return {
            requestEvent : requestEvent,
        };
    }

})();
```

Comment: you need to use `$q` and then `defer.resolve ` to make it work

Comment: Inject `$q` and return `$q.when(gas)` instead of just gas, and it will work.

Comment: You should use then/catch instead of success/error though. success/error handlers are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be chained, it should return a settled promise.

```
monitorData.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function monitorData($http, $q) {
    var requestEvent = function(eventid) {
        var gas = "Event " + eventid + " requested.."
        console.log(gas);
        return $q.resolve(gas);
    };

    return {
        requestEvent : requestEvent,
    };
}
```

And by the way, `success` and `error` are deprecated legacy methods. It is always `then` and `catch` now.

Comment: So I simple replace '.success' with '.then' and '.error' with '.catch'?

Comment: That's correct. `success` and `error` are there for compatibility. It may be also a single `then` with two callback arguments. There is some  difference between .`.then(..., ...)` and `.then(...).catch(...)`. `catch` will catch error from both `$http` result and `then`.

Comment: Awesome, this worked and thank you as well for the insight on the deprecated success/error.

Answer (score 1):

`success` and `error` are part of the  promise and you are not returning promise.

To make it work,you should use [defer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) which `resolve` to `success`

and return promise which later chained with `.success` and `.error`

```
monitorData.$inject = ['$http','$q'];

var defer = $q.defer();
function monitorData($http) {
        var requestEvent = function(eventid) {
            var gas = "Event " + eventid + " requested.."

            defer.resolve(gas)
            return defer.promise;
        };

        return {
            requestEvent : requestEvent,
        };
    }
```

Comment: And the code in the controller would stay the same with the . success and .error?

Comment: It's a lot easier to just return `$q.when(gas)`.

Comment: Yes,you can,But basically we use this one because to make consistency with ecma6